# mergeSort in python - object NoneType error

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a simple merge sort in python with the aim to split the function into mergeSort and merge. My code looks like this:

```
def merge_sort(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    else:
        m = len(s) // 2
        s1 = merge_sort(s[:m])
        s2 = merge_sort(s[m:])
        print(merge(s1, s2))
        return merge(s1, s2)



def merge(s1, s2):
    i=0
    j=0
    k=0
    while i < len(s1) and j< len(s2):
        if s1[i] < s2[j]:
            s[k] = s1[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            s[k] = s2[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < len(s1):
        s[k] = s1[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < len(s2):
        s[k] = s2[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
```

now I do believe that i understood the basic idea of merge sort, but when I test my code

I get the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

After 2hours I gave up and build my code different and it worked, but its still nagging me because I believe the code above is correct and Im just missing some detail.
I would be most thankful if someone could explain it to me.
Thanks!

Comment: `merge_sort` ends with `return merge(s1, s2)`, but `merge` doesn't return anything explicitely, so it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def merge_sort(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    else:
        m = len(s) // 2
        s1 = merge_sort(s[:m])
        s2 = merge_sort(s[m:])
        print(merge(s1, s2))
        return merge(s1, s2)




def merge(s1, s2):
    s = []
    i=0
    j=0
    while i < len(s1) and j< len(s2):
        if s1[i] < s2[j]:
            s.append(s1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            s.append(s2[j])
            j += 1

    while i < len(s1):
        s.append(s1[i])
        i += 1

    while j < len(s2):
        s.append(s2[j])
        j += 1
    return s
```